# EGARCH and GARCH effects with White Noise squared residuals

Tags: option-pricing, volatility, regression, garch

I'm asked to model a series which it's returns are white noise and after adjusting a regression like $r_t=c$ and looking it's squared residuals (white noise too) I'm asked to adjust a GARCH and EGARCH model to them.

Surprisingly, all coefficients both in GARCH and EGARCH are significative, how is this possible if the squared residuals were white noise?

Comment: Hi:  How are you concluding that  the squared residuals from the regression are white noise ? It's a little unusual that the squared residuals would be white noise since they are always positive.

Comment: From the correlogram, I cannot reject the null in any case.

Comment: Hi: I'm not sure what the best way is to do the test but its probably better to use some analytical-formal test like some analog of box-leung. I'm confident that there must be one but I don't know it off the top of my head.

Comment: Hi: It looks like you can do a regression on the squared residuals and then use the LM test. https://www.cemfi.es/~arellano/lmtesting.pdf